# Playsound skipping first half-second of file unless a music player program happens to be running

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, audio

I have some very short (<1-2 second) WAV files which are not playing reliably.  On a fast Windows 8 machine, they never play unless some kind of audio player (windows Media Player, iTunes) happens to be open and has played something (anything), and then they play every time.

I have other (also short) WAV files which do play every time.  From the exact same call.  They all reside in the program's directory.

When they don't play, Playsound still returns true. Here is the win32 C++ call:

```
    Playsound( L"mfile.wav", NULL, SND_ASYNC | SND_FILENAME );
```

It seems that this test computer (and presumably other Windows 8 systems) has some kind of optimization which takes a while to "warm up" the sound system.  Even if I ask Windows Media Player to play one of the file, no sound comes out ... the first time.  But when I click play from then on, it plays fine every time.  iTunes takes a long time to decide to play the file, and then it always works.  Turning on/off sound enhancements via Control Panel has no effect.

Any ideas?  Is there something I can do to "activate" the sound system like theses media players do?  Because my sound won't play the first time, or ever, unless one of these other programs is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity's sake, I'll note the "solution" here, and some relevant facts.

Both Playsound and mcisendstring suffered from this failure to play certain short files on a particular system.  I suspect the cause was an NVIDIA card/driver, because a different Windows 8 system didn't manifest this problem.

Third try was the charm, though, and when I implemented the call via DirectShow, it worked reliably. In fact, just opening a DirectShow connection was enough to enable mcisendstring to work successfully on its own (this must be why the calls worked when WMP or iTunes was also running on the system).  Too bad DirectShow (like almost everything else) has been superceded by Microsoft Media Foundation, but that was much too complicated for simply playing a short wav file.